# Paypal Pro, Does not autofill the Billing block if used postcode search. Where the problem is?a

Tags: paypal, postcode

I am using civipostcode extension with my Paypal pro Processor. https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.module.civicrmpostcodelookup

When I search and select a postcode from the result on a contribution page, although I have selected "My Billing address is same as Home Address", it does not get autofilled.

But If I manually type home address fields it works perfectly fine!!

Can anyone give me a hint please, where the problem may be? in the Extension or in Core or Settings in my server? So I can submit a bug fix request accordingly. Thanks